# Sleeping queries in mysql?

Tags: mysql

My MySQL database (Innodb) has a high volume of concurrent, long running INSERT queries being performed into it.

The queries are from my node.js application, in which I'm using node-mysql bindings, specifically using 'pool()' for connection pooling.

When I'm monitoring the queries via mytop, I'm seeing a number of long running connections in 'sleep' (running in excess of 600 seconds).

I'm usure whether this is a query thats hanging, due to row locking etc, or whether these are just connections from the connection pool?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As MySQL documentation on [thread command values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/thread-commands.html) (that's the equivalent of your `cmd` field) says

> Sleep
>
> The thread is waiting for the client to send a new statement to it.

This means that any connection with a `sleep` status is waiting for a new instruction to be sent, it is not working on anything at the moment. If the connection would be busy, then you would see a different value in the `cmd` field, and a more detailed description in the `state` field. The possible values for the latter are described in the MySQL documentation on [General Thread States](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/general-thread-states.html) (you can find statuses related to waiting for locks as well).

Based on the above information, I cannot tell you if those sleeping connections are from the connection pool (you can do that based on the IP address probably), but they are definitely no queries that got stuck.

Comment: To clarify, these are not indicative of queries getting stuck because of row locking?

Comment: See last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: @Thanks - do these sleeping connections consume cpu or memory resources? In other words, should i be worried or can I leave them?

Comment: They do consume some cpu and memory, since they are separate threads with open tcp connections. Whether you need to worry about them I cannot precisely say, since I'm not familiar with your system. Probably they are not, since your system should have enough capacity do deal with them if all of them come alive at the same time - otherwise why would you allow so many concurrent database connections and use connection pooling in the first place.

Comment: Obviously, if the max number of connections parameter is seriously misconfigured (set to a higher value than your system can deal with), and your system is already running close to 100% cpu and memory utilisation with those connections in sleeping status, then you have a problem. If you have any follow up questions, then pls ask them in their own post. Even this last one has nothing to do with the original question.